# Patent trial data set

Tags: reference-request, data

I am looking for a data set that would list patent trials that involve an academic institution, if possible with the date, the parties involved and the outcome.

I am aware of [this list](http://www.academyofinventors.com/pdf/NAI-IPO-Top-100-Universities-2014.pdf) of number of US patents awarded by academic institutions in 2014, as well as (1), which lists the evolution of yearly aggregate costs for resolved lawsuits, unresolved lawsuits,
and nonlitigated assertion for patent trials (non-academic specific), but I couldn't find a similar data set for academic patent trials.

---

(1) Bessen, James, and Michael J. Meurer. "[The Direct Costs from NPE Disputes](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=15273207909379906758&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" Cornell L. Rev. 99 (2013): 387.

Comment: Have you tried asking a law library's reference desk how you could research this?

Comment: @keshlam No, there is no library near me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're asking about a (presumably, preferably, open) data set, this question might be a better fit for the *Open Data* SE site. However, since you express some interest in references and I was quite curious about what information on the topic is available, I will try to answer your question here.

I would start searching for the relevant data sets, at least, on *U.S. Patent and Trademark Office (USPTO)* and *European Patent Office (EPO)*. Doing so reveals some data sets that certainly could be useful for the task at hand. In particular, the following *data sets* & *services* might be of interest:

**Data sets and databases**

- [USPTO Patent Assignment Dataset](http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/electronic-data-products/patent-assignment-dataset)
- [USPTO Historical Patent Data Files](http://www.uspto.gov/learning-and-resources/electronic-data-products/historical-patent-data-files)
- [USPTO's PatentsView Datasets](http://www.patentsview.org/web) (query tool and APIs seem to be unavailable at present)
- [Electronic Document Information System (EDIS)](https://edis.usitc.gov/edis3-external/app) by U.S. International Trade Commission
- [EPO Datasets](https://data.epo.org/data.html)
- [Databases by Darts-ip](https://www.darts-ip.com/world/patents/academics-and-students/solutions-for-you) (commercial; see "Patent focused" quadrant)
- [LITALERT (LITigation ALERTs) Database](https://stneasy.cas.org/dbss/help.LITALERT.html) (commercial)

**Services (search + analytics, etc.)**

- [Lex Machina](https://lexmachina.com)
- [Docket Navigator](http://home.docketnavigator.com/overview/docket-navigator)
- [Patexia Litigation Search](https://www.patexia.com/ip-research/lawsuits)

**Papers / Books (*bonus*)**

- [The effects of patent litigation on university licensing efforts](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/222679773_The_effects_of_patent_litigation_on_university_licensing_efforts)
- [Innovation and litigation: Tensions between universities and patents and how to fix them](http://digitalcommons.law.yale.edu/yjolt/vol15/iss2/1)
- [The trials of academe: The new era of campus litigation](http://www.hup.harvard.edu/catalog.php?isbn=9780674035676)

P.S. Obviously, for most data sets and databases, you would have to perform data pre-processing to select/associate data relevant to academic institutions and, perhaps, some additional steps. Considering your background, it should not be a big problem. I hope that my answer is helpful.